# How to save a file sent from NodeJS with POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, requestjs

I created the following function to load a stream file. This stream is sent to the address specified with a POST. At the destination, I have another NodeJS service that with ExpressJS "capture" this POST but I have no idea how I can save the file to the destination.

NodeJS on my PC:

```
function sendFileToRaspberry(filePath) {
    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://x.x.x.x:8080/api/print',
        qs: {file: fs.createReadStream(filePath)},
        headers:
            {
                'cache-control': 'no-cache'
            }
    };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);

        console.log(body);
    });
}
```

NodeJS on my Raspberry:

```
app.post('/api/print', function (req, res) {

    ORIGINAL_IP = req.ip.replace("::ffff:", '');
    console.log("Received a print request from: " + ORIGINAL_IP);

    // Test history data for /api/printer API
    var file = req.query.file;
    console.log("Test data: " + file);
    util.inspect(file);

});
```

But in the console log I get:

> Received a print request from: y.y.y.y
>
> Test data: [object Object]

How can I save this file on Rasp?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a expressjs middleware helper like `express-fileupload`, [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).

I think, you have use `Multipart Form Uploads` to upload a file via http POST.

Client side (Your PC)

```
function sendFileToRaspberry(filePath) {
    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://x.x.x.x:8080/api/print',
        formData: {
            file: fs.createReadStream(filePath)
        },
        headers: {
            'cache-control': 'no-cache'
        }
    };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);

        console.log(body);
    });
}
```